# How can I check if there is an image file a particular location in workspace in java?

Tags: java

I need to check if image exists at the path given. I have the path. This is how I am trying it:

```
String imagePath = "_images/blogimages/fileName.jpg";
File f = new File(imagePath);
if (f.exists()) {
     return imagePath;
} else {
     return "someOtherPath";
}
```

However, it always goes into else. f.exists() doesn't seem to be working with image file. I need to return the imagePath when image exists at given path. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try with the absolute path of `fileName.jpg`. Also, this has nothing to do with image files. Please modify the question title to make it about file existence check.

Comment: Can't use absolute path unfortunately.

Comment: you must have missed something about the relative path you are using. Your `_images`  folder must be at the same level as `src` folder which contains your java class

Comment: @Kaustubh: Well, then ... think of it this way: how will your Java code know the location of the `_images` directory?